# Issue with Error 404 on delete request only

Tags: jquery, node.js, ejs

new to node JS, having an issue with Delete Request returning 404 not found. I'm connecting ok to the DB, able to add to the database with the post request, it's the delete request only that's causing an issue. This is from my controller file:

```
app.delete('/:item', function(req,res)
    {
        steTodo.find({item:req.params.item.replace(/\-/g, " ")}).remove(function(err,data)
        {   
            if(err) throw err;
            res.json(data);
        });
```

This is the jquery:

```
$('.removeClass').on('click', function()
    {
        var item = $(this).text().replace(/ /g, "-");
        $.ajax({
          type: 'DELETE',
          url: '/' + item,
          success: function(data)
          {

            //do something with the data via front-end framework
            alert('Successfully called');
            location.reload();
          },
          error: function(jqxhr, status, exception)
          { 
            alert('Exception:', status);
          }
        });      
    });
```

Here is the error I see in the console:

```
jquery.min.js:2 DELETE http://localhost:3000/get-flowers 404 (Not Found)
```

Any ideas or thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Its look like its calling `get-flowers` route rather that concidering it is as a url param.

If you change to this.

```
app.delete('/', function(req,res)
    {
      const { query } = req;
      const { item } = query;
        steTodo.find({item:item.replace(/\-/g, " ")}).remove(function(err,data)
        {   
            if(err) throw err;
            res.json(data);
        });
```

and ajax call like that,

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'DELETE',
          url: '/?item=' + item,
          success: function(data)
          {

            //do something with the data via front-end framework
            alert('Successfully called');
            location.reload();
          },
          error: function(jqxhr, status, exception)
          { 
            alert('Exception:', status);
          }
        });
```

It should work now.

Comment: Sorry for delay in responding and thank you for your help, but this hasn't worked from me. I'm still getting the error in the chrome console: jquery.min.js:2 DELETE http://localhost:3000/?item=get-flowers 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

change your route like :

```
app.delete('/delete/:item', function(req,res) { ... }
```

in Ajax function :

```
  $.ajax({
      type: 'DELETE',
      url: '/delete/' + item,
      ...
   });
```

Comment: Hi Sorry for delay in responding. I tried this, it didn't work for me unfortunately.

Comment: open inspect Element , check network tab , make sure your AJAX request is send to server ?